# connect a server and client side on a visual studio project

Tags: c#, javascript, google-maps-api-2

**We wrote this code in HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/markers.js">
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
</head>
<body><div id="map"></div>
<input type="button" id="showmarkers" value="Show Markers" />

</body>
</html>
```

**and this code in JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#map").css({
        height:600,
        width: 2000
    });
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.2402893696987, 34.7672211844361);
  MYMAP.init('#map', myLatLng, 11);

  $("#showmarkers").click(function(e){
        MYMAP.placeMarkers('markers.xml');
});
});

var MYMAP = {
  map: null,
    bounds: null
}

MYMAP.init = function(selector, latLng, zoom) {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:zoom,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}

MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
    $.get(filename, function(xml){
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
            var name = $(this).find('name').text();
            var address = $(this).find('address').text();

            // create a new LatLng point for the marker
            var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
            var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));

            // extend the bounds to include the new point
            MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                map: MYMAP.map
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var html='<strong>'+name+'</strong.><br />'+address;
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
            });
            MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);
        });

    });
}
```

We want to use this code to display a google map on our ASP. NET (C#) website. Is it possible to load this entire code as is to one of our pages on our website?
Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Add a new `.aspx` file to your ASP.NET project and simply replace its default content with your HTML.
Then, add a script block in the `<head>` section:

```
<script language="javascript">

</script>
```

And in between there, paste your javascript code.

Now add a link to this page from any other page in your project.
That should work just fine.